# Count how many words in each sentence

Tags: c#

I'm stuck on how to count how many words are in each sentence, an example of this is: `string sentence = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good."` 
and have it come out like:

```
//sentence1: 4 words
//sentence2: 3 words
//sentence3: 2 words
```

I can get the number of sentences

```
    public int GetNoOfWords(string s)
    {
        return s.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
    label2.Text = (GetNoOfWords(sentance).ToString());
```

and i can get the number of words in the whole string

```
    public int CountWord (string text)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] != ' ')
            {
                if ((i + 1) == text.Length)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(text[i + 1] == ' ')
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        return count;
    }
```

then button1

```
        int words = CountWord(sentance);
        label4.Text = (words.ToString());
```

*But* I can't count how many words are in each sentence.

Comment: @DanielLopez - I can't see how it WOULDN'T be a duplicate. ;-)

Comment: @RJLohan I don't know but hasn't this question been asked countless times? I am pretty sure he didn't do the research. I am just saying my opinion, I might be wrong.

Comment: @DanielLopez - no, I agree with you completely. Somewhere in the vicinity of 3500 duplicates; http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+count+words+in+sentence

Comment: Opps I must of not looked hard enough or wasn't searching the right things :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use Split instead?

> ```
>         var sentences = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.";
>
>         foreach (var sentence in sentences.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
>             Console.WriteLine(sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count());
> ```

Comment: Yea Thanks! this works and counts all the sentences but it shows a "1" at the end, why is that?

Comment: Update the code, give it a go :) It's because the period in the end resulted to a 'blank' sentence.

Comment: how would i get this to append to new lines in a textbox? since it only displays the last one?(sorry noob question)

Comment: Found it i just add a + to the = so +=

Answer (score 5):

Instead of looping over the string as you do in `CountWords` I would just use;

```
 int words = s.Split(' ').Length;
```

It's much more clean and simple. You split on white spaces which returns an array of all the words, the length of that array is the number of words in the string.

Comment: @DanielLopez No. The length is taking the number of elements, not the final index. final index plus one is the length.

Answer (score 1):

If you want number of words in each sentence, you need to

```
string s = "This is a sentence. Also this counts. This one is also a thing.";
string[] sentences = s.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string sentence in sentences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sentence.Split(' ').Length + " words in sentence *" + sentence + "*");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CountWord on each element of the array returned by s.Split:

```
string sentence = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.";
string[] words = sentence.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;

for (string sentence in sentences)
{
    int noOfWordsInSentence = CountWord(sentence);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "hello how are you. I am good. that's good.";
string[] sentences = s.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
IEnumerable<int> wordsPerSentence = sentences.Select(s => s.Trim().Split(' ').Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in several answers here, look at String functions like Split, Trim, Replace, etc to get you going. All answers here will solve your simple example, but here are some sentences which they may fail to analyse correctly;

```
"Hello, how are you?" (no '.' to parse on)
"That apple costs $1.50."  (a '.' used as a decimal)
"I   like     whitespace    .    "   
"Word"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a count, I'd avoid `Split()` -- it takes up unnecessary space. Perhaps:

```
static int WordCount(string s)
{
    int wordCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i]) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i + 1]) && i > 0)
            wordCount++;
    return ++wordCount;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(WordCount(" H elloWor    ld g  ")); // prints "4"
}
```

It counts based on the number of spaces (1 space = 2 words). Consecutive spaces are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Does your spelling of sentence in:

```
int words = CountWord(sentance);
```

have anything to do with it?

Comment: @DanielLopez I don't understand. CountWord is a function supplied by DarkN3ss above.